# Javascript Object Property Undefined (GM_getValue(), GM_listValues(), Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, javascript-objects, tampermonkey

this is probably something simple, I dunno, but I am trying to create a string from an object returned by Tampermonkey (basically Greasemonkey for Chrome) `GM_getValue()` function.

The final code looks like this...

```
//Call GM_listValues() to get keys of all stored values
var keys = GM_listValues();

//Code to create CSV string out of first 10 records
var csvString = '';
for (j=0; j<10; ++j) {
    var temp = GM_getValue(keys[j]);

    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.id + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.time + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.outcome + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.condition + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.wager + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.chance + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '"' + temp.profit + '"' + ",";
    csvString = csvString + '\n';
}

//Code to download CSV
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

However, the result is a bunch of undefined fields.  When I debug, I see that the variable `keys` is getting populated correctly with the keys.   I see that the variable `temp` is getting the correct data as well.  When I do `typeof temp` it says `object` so I assume it's an object.

When I `console.log(temp)` it says `json_val: {"id":"2132867232","time":"07:52","outcome":"84","condition":">1","wager":"0.50000m฿","chance":"98 %","profit":"+0.00520"}`

Does the `json_val:` have something to do with why doing `console.log(temp.id)` returns `undefined`?

I also tried `temp["id"]` and get undefined as well.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the grants at the top of the file.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @grant     GM_getValue
// @grant     GM_listValues
// ==/UserScript==
```